# Determine whether the following vectors are linearly independent.

Tags: vector-spaces

I have the following question:

"Examine whether the following vectors are linearly dependent or independent. For linear dependency, write a vector as linear combination of the others. For linear independence, check if the vectors form a basis for the respective vector space."

$f_1, f_2, f_3 \in C(\mathbb{R})$ (the vector space of the continuous functions $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$) with $f_1(x) = \sin^2{x}, \ f_2(x) = cos^2(x) \ \& f_3(x) = \cos{2x}.$

---

Progress so far:

Check for linear independence: Setting $x = \pi(n - \frac{1}{2}) $ with $n \in \mathbb{z}$ & $a_1 = a_2 = a_3 = 1$ demonstrates that $a_1 f_1(x) + a_2 f_2(x) + a_3 f_3(x) = 0$ is **not true** only for the case that $a = 0$.

$\therefore$ I need to write $f_1, f_2 \  \& \ f_3$ as linear combinations of each other, at which point i get confused, as the value of a linear combination the functions depends not only on the values $a_1, \ a_2 \ \& \ a_3$, but also on the variable $x$.

Can anyone help me from here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint. Note that by the [addition formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TrigonometricAdditionFormulas.html),
$$\cos(2x)=\cos(x+x)=\cos(x)\cdot \cos(x)-\sin(x)\cdot \sin(x).$$

Comment: damn, that pretty much nails it. And now to embarrass myself:


Rewriting the addition formula in terms of the functions $f_1, f_2, f_3$ furnishes the following linear combinations: $f_1 = f_2 - f_3$, $f_2 = f_3 + f_1$ & $f_3 = f_2 - f_1$, at which point we are done?

Answer (score 0):

$cos(2x)=2cos^2(x)-1=2cos^2(x)-(sin^2(x)+cos^2(x))$ you deduce that $f_3=2f_2-f_1-f_2$ so they are not independent.

Answer (score 0):

for $x=0$ we get: $b+c=0$ for $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$ we get: $a-c=0$ and for $x=\pi$: $b+c=0$